# Ruby Sorbet Hash Typecheck

Tags: ruby, sorbet

I want to understand why Sorbet does not complain for this example: [Example](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20true%0Aextend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0Asig%20%7Bparams%28x%3A%20T%3A%3AHash%5BString%2C%20String%5D%29.void%7D%0Adef%20foo%28x%29%0A%20%20x.each%20do%20%7Ck%2C%20v%7C%0A%20%20%20%20puts%20%22key%20%3D%20%23%7Bk%7D%2C%20value%20%3D%20%23%7Bv%7D%22%0A%20%20end%0Aend%0A%0Ahash%20%3D%20%7B%7D%0Ahash%5B1%5D%20%3D%201%0Afoo%28hash%29%0A):

```rb
sig {params(x: T::Hash[String, String]).void}
def foo(x)
  x.each do |k, v|
    puts "key = #{k}, value = #{v}"
  end
end

hash = {}
hash[1] = 1
foo(hash) #  I'd expect this to fail to type-check
```

I have declared `foo` to take in a hash of [String, String] but I am passing a hash of [Integer, Integer]. I thought Sorbet would complain here...

Is there a way to make it error out for these kinds of scenarios?

Comment: I would recommend posting your code in the question. Links can die but SO is forever.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `hash` is not of type `T::Hash[Integer, Integer]`, but `T::Hash[T.untyped, T.untyped]`. You can see that by using `T.reveal_type`:

```
hash = {}
hash[1] = 1
T.reveal_type(hash) # Revealed type: {} (shape of T::Hash[T.untyped, T.untyped])
```

This happens because Sorbet doesn't have information about your hash when it's created. The solution is to explicitly initialize it:

```
hash = T::Hash[Integer, Integer].new
hash[1] = 1
foo(hash) # Expected T::Hash[String, String] but found T::Hash[Integer, Integer] for argument x
```

You can see the full code [here](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20true%0Aextend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0Asig%20%7Bparams%28x%3A%20T%3A%3AHash%5BString%2C%20String%5D%29.void%7D%0Adef%20foo%28x%29%0A%20%20x.each%20do%20%7Ck%2C%20v%7C%0A%20%20%20%20puts%20%22key%20%3D%20%23%7Bk%7D%2C%20value%20%3D%20%23%7Bv%7D%22%0A%20%20end%0Aend%0A%0Ahash%20%3D%20T%3A%3AHash%5BInteger%2C%20Integer%5D.new%0Ahash%5B1%5D%20%3D%201%0Afoo%28hash%29%0A)

The underlying reason is because the `hash` is initially interpreted as a `Shape` (see https://sorbet.org/docs/shapes), without any type information.